# Anyone found a PowerShell Syntax highlighting or IntelliSense plugin for Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, plugins, intellisense, syntax-highlighting

Has anyone found a plugin for Visual Studio to allow for PowerShell syntax highlighting or IntelliSense? If not, does anyone have any idea why not?  I keep hoping someone else with copious free time would have tackled this by now. I have hope since other folks have managed to take the limited documentation and build custom IntelliSense providers for other languages such as [NHaml](http://sentia.com.au/2008/05/i-love-haml-but-i.html).

Edit: To clarify,I'm not looking for a list of IDEs that can be used to develop PowerShell . I spend 90% of my day in Visual Studio.  It already does a really good job of slicing and dicing code. That is the IDE I prefer to use to edit all text and code.  The lack of PowerShell syntax highlighting now that I work with PowerShell scripts is down right painful.

Comment: There has been talk of a PowerShell based build environment for upcoming versions of Visual Studio, but there is no current integration.

Comment: Partial duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/171514/5314

Comment: I've recently found a new extension that does syntax coloring for .ps1 files in VS2012: TextHighlighterExtension2012. You can use Nuget to add it as an extension in VS2012 (Tools -> Extensions & Updates, select Online and enter "TextHighlighterExtensions2012"). Or you can visit the homepage at http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fd129629-a1a1-417c-ac80-c9ac7a67b968. This extensions also apparently does some limited intellisense also. I only installed it 10 minutes ago so not much exploration yet. But the colors work and honor my VS theme. Woot!

Comment: Old question, but good news -- if you're on Windows 10 you get syntax highlighting out of the box and the ISE has offered full Intellisense for a while.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a useful one: [PowerGUI VS Extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/01516103-d487-4a7e-bb40-c15ec709afa3).

Comment: That's a stub project. Some code is written and it does some intellisense on someone's machine. But it's not usable on others' machines. And an unusable solution isn't a solution at all.

Comment: I don't understand why this is marked as an answer. Anybody can put a placeholder page out on the internet and give it a name that looks like the answer, but if it doesn't do what it claims, it's not the answer.

Answer (score 17):

### Update 2013-08-20

Adam Driscoll has recently announced the [PowerShell Tools for Visual Studio](https://github.com/adamdriscoll/poshtools/tree/dev) as successor of his former [PowerGUI Visual Studio Extension](http://powerguivsx.codeplex.com/) - see his blog post about [The Future of PowerGUI VSX](http://csharpening.net/?p=1673) for details, where he acknowledges the drawbacks of the predecessor outlined by Simon Gillbee (see previous update below) and describes how they will be addressed by removing the dependency on PowerGUI:

> [...] By **embedding the PowerGUI editor directly in Visual Studio** it caused a multitude of problems because it **really wasn’t a true language integration but more like a hack**.
>
> [...] PowerGUI VSX v2 will offer
>   true Visual Studio language support for PowerShell. **It uses the Visual
>   Studio editor and the raw PowerShell debugger, tokenizer and
>   completion engine.** Currently, the requirement is PowerShell v3 and
>   Visual Studio 2012. This requirement may change depending on community
>   support and adoption. *[emphasis mine]*

---

### Update 2013-07-31

Simon Gillbee has just [referenced/promoted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271292/anyone-found-a-powershell-syntax-highlighting-or-intellisense-plugin-for-visual/3345147?noredirect=1#comment26247025_3345147) a PowerShell syntax highlighting alternative, that doesn't expose the drawbacks of the [PowerGUI Visual Studio Extension](http://powerguivsx.codeplex.com/) he [previously summarized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271292/anyone-found-a-powershell-syntax-highlighting-or-intellisense-plugin-for-visual/3345147?noredirect=1#comment25209604_3345147):

- [TextHighlighterExtension2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fd129629-a1a1-417c-ac80-c9ac7a67b968) (Visual Studio 2012)
- [TextHighlighterExtension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6706b602-6f10-4fd1-8e14-75840f855569) (Visual Studio 2010)

---

### Initial Answer

The recently released [PowerGUI Visual Studio Extension](http://powerguivsx.codeplex.com/) adds PowerShell IntelliSense support to Visual Studio. While it depends on the (free) [PowerGUI](http://powergui.org/) graphical user interface and script editor, reusing this editor component should be a sign of maturity rather than an impediment I'd hope. (See Kirk Munros [PowerShell support in Visual Studio!](http://poshoholic.com/2010/06/16/powershell-support-in-visual-studio/) blog post for an introduction.)

Being a 1.0 there are still some [minor issues](http://powerguivsx.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic) with the extension as such, but Adam Driscoll seems to be pretty active tackling these - the PowerShell syntax highlighting and IntelliSense support is working most excellent for me already!

Comment: It's a bit of a shame that it took this long, but, behold, PowerShell is being syntax highlighted within my Visual Studio 2010 IDE. Unfortunately, it lacks intellisense and it's black/color on white whereas my config has everything white/color on black. Better than just a solid foreground color, though.

Comment: I actually think this extension is a step backwards. It replaces the entire text editor with their own editor. So none of my visual studio customizations, colors, keyboard shortcuts, other extensions (such as CodeRush to do Ctrl-Arrow to move through camel case identifiers) work. I use Visual Studio because it's a top-notch text editor. Don't replace it. That's just stupid.

Comment: I've recently found a new extension that does syntax coloring for .ps1 files in VS2012: TextHighlighterExtension2012. You can use Nuget to add it as an extension in VS2012 (Tools -> Extensions & Updates, select Online and enter "TextHighlighterExtensions2012"). Or you can visit the homepage at http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fd129629-a1a1-417c-ac80-c9ac7a67b968. This extensions also apparently does some limited intellisense also. I only installed it 10 minutes ago so not much exploration yet. But the colors work and honor my VS theme. Woot!

Comment: @SimonGillbee - thanks much for making me aware of this alternative, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I'm happy to see the new PowerShell Tools for Visual Studio. I've installed it in my new VS2012 environment and so far it looks good. Thank you for the hard work Adam!

Answer (score 5):

I have not seen anything about Visual Studio  Intellisense for PowerShell scripts.

I recommend you to try some other tools like:

- [PowerTab](http://thepowershellguy.com/blogs/posh/pages/powertab.aspx)
- [PowerGUI](http://www.powergui.org/index.jspa)

Look this screen cast:

[image]
<sub>(source: [aaronlerch.com](http://www.aaronlerch.com/files/blog/Powershell_Intellisense.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The [PowerConsole](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/67620d8c-93dd-4e57-aa86-c9404acbd7b3?SRC=VSIDE) extension for VS2010 is very nice and looks promising. I am not sure though that it is suitable (or able) to edit scripts. It is worth to try in any case.