# Can I get intellisense in powershell?

Tags: powershell, intellisense

***Edit:*** Anyone coming to the question now. Please look at the dates. This is a very, very, old question from the first version of PowerShell. Everything is now different

Just starting out with PowerShell, I would love to have intellisense support for writing PowerShell scripts.  Tab-completion works great so you would think it would exist somewhere, but the only thing I can find an article from 2007 - hardly up to date.

Is there an extension somewhere that gives you this ability?

How about an editor?

Comment: I looks like this is available on Windows 2012 and above.

Comment: @NTDLS intellisense is? or just tab-completion? I use powershell daily and it certainly does not have anything like intellisense.

Comment: Do you use it on windows 2012? It appears to be more than just tab-completion, but to your point it is a far-cry from visual studio quality/features 2013 I ntellisense.

Comment: Sure! But it immediately stops working the instant you call it from inside of a function's scope. In other words, it's standard microsoft broken stuff.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Windows PowerShell ISE which is installed with later versions of PowerShell has got built-in intellisense.

Also Visual Studio Code with the PowerShell extension is another option

And ISE Steroids if you want to stay with ISE

*But seems direction is VS Code, especially with Core*

Answer (score 16):

Try this -

http://powergui.org/index.jspa

This is a good editor with intellisense

Comment: +1 for recommending PowerGUI - its editor component has recently been made available as a Visual Studio Extension too, see my answer on [Anyone found a PowerShell Syntax highlighting or IntelliSense plugin for Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271292/anyone-found-a-powershell-syntax-highlighting-or-intellisense-plugin-for-visual-s/3345147#3345147) for details.

Answer (score 6):

Have a look on [PowerTab](http://thepowershellguy.com/blogs/posh/pages/powertab.aspx).

Comment: I second this recommendation.  It doesn't replace a good editor, but this is such a great addition to the console.

Answer (score 4):

Also [PowerShell Plus](http://www.idera.com/Products/PowerShell/PowerShell-Plus-Technical-Features/) (commercial). Or you can wait for PowerShell 2.0 and hopefully get [Graphical Windows PowerShell](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/topics/winpsh/graphical2.mspx).

Comment: Why wait for V2? Why not use it now. It is very close to official release. (One month?) I think that unless you have a good reason for staying with V1, you should move to V2. The Integrated Scripting Environment is indeed pretty nice, and it does have intellisense.

Answer (score 2):

[PowerSE](http://WWW.POWERSE.COM) is a free PowerShell Editor that includes Intellisense (PowerShell, WMI, and .NET)

Features:

- Includes Auto-Script creation feature - execute a cmdlet, look at the results in a grid view, select and sort columns, then tell it to generate the PowerShell for you.
- Community button to search TechNet and PoshCode for samples.
- Debug features such as breakpoints and stepping through code.
- Watch window to drill into PowerShell variables.
- Context sensitive help.
- Imbedded console window with command recorder.

Answer (score 2):

Try visual studio code with powershell extension. It works better than Windows PowerShell ISE for me.

Answer (score 1):

PSReadline now has intellisense right in the console based on the command history.    https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/announcing-psreadline-2-1-with-predictive-intellisense/

To enable in powershell 7:

```
Set-PSReadLineOption -PredictionSource History
```

You can also get that version of psreadline in powershell 5.1.

```
Install-Module PSReadLine -RequiredVersion 2.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the best way that you write TabExpansion.
There are no Autocomplteion tools for posh, like C#'s IntelliSence.
They can't get even $_'s properties even if you use just a standard Cmdlet.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell ISE v3 has Intellisense

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=27548